# Stuck on which option to do

Tags: oaths, kaffarah

Assalamu alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuhu,

Few of my posts are related to Kaffarah yameen. But I’m really stuck and I would like to know if you are 13 and you broke an oath, which option do you do? The fasting for 3 days? Because that’s the only one from the others a 13 year old can do right?

Jazakallah khair.

Comment: For answering this we need to know: Are you mature (legally responsible)? Do you have wealth (money) that you call your own? ...

Comment: Well, the money is my father’s, I don’t have money that is my own. All the money in the house belongs to my father as he earns it.

Comment: And where is your confusion then?

Comment: What if there’s a bank account under my name or something like that?

Comment: Also what if I won a prize and it was money, but then later decide to give the money to my parents. Is this now their money?

Comment: These are all new questions which IMO have answers on the site. The point which is relevant to kaffarah is you don't have money in your own possession so you don't have that much options left. Assuming you need to do kaffarah at all which is already shown in the answer to your last question.

Comment: Ok Jazakallah khair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your very first post ([Kaffarah for breaking an oath confusion](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55870/kaffarah-for-breaking-an-oath-confusion)) you asked whether a 13 years old person must expiate for breaking oaths.

In Islam the age of maturity is not fixed by an age, unless no sign of maturity appears on the individual else once one is mature and legally responsible (mature and well minded) one must follow the rules and therefore is asked for expiation I've addressed this in my answer on your question [Must the fasts for Kaffarah of breaking an oath be consecutive?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/55891/must-the-fasts-for-kaffarah-of-breaking-an-oath-be-consecutive).

So until now we don't know whether you are legally responsible or not. So this question still needs clarification.

Assuming you are mature and legally responsible we may move to the next issue which is do you have the means for a payment of an expiation. In the comments you say you have no possession over wealth (money). This means the only expiation you are allowed to perform is fasting in case that you broke an oath.

There might be the possibility that you ask your parents to give you some of the money that was saved for you to pay an expiation, but honestly I wonder if they follow your instructions and I wonder if the payment of your parents for your misdeeds ins this case count.

Comment: In Sha Allah, I will fast. Jazakallah khair.