# Kaffarah for breaking oath?

Tags: oaths, kaffarah

Do i have to give them physically even tho the food is not from my money (my parent's money)
and can someone else distributed the food for me ?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. If you are not able (financially) to feed others than this kafarah is not the correct one for you!

Comment: The relevant kaffarah depends on your ability and possibilities. You can't pay for something if you don't earn money. And none can do it for you as long as you don't fulfill the conditions yourself. See also https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/55891/13438